# bash: rsync with options as variable

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I am writing bash script, which in some part will rsync files over ssh. Unfortunately I am facing problem with keeping rsync options as variable. Please take a look below:

```
    # variables
    directory="/etc"
    backupDirectory="/backup"
    incrementalBackup="/incremental"
    options="-a -e 'ssh -p 10022' -b --backup-dir=$incrementalBackup --delete"
    # rsync
    rsync $options user@server:$directory $backupDirectory
```

Unfortunately above script fails with rsync error:

```
    Unexpected remote arg: user@server:/etc
    rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1201) [sender=3.0.6]
```

What I saw during script debugging is the fact, that ssh options ('ssh -p 10022') are treated as rsync options.
The question is how to pass correctly those additional ssh settings into rsync?
Thanks in advance for a tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eval`.  Try:

```
eval rsync $options user@server:$directory $backupDirectory
```

Comment: The use of `eval` is not recommended when there are other options available.

Answer (score 14):

Use an array; it's why they were added to `bash`:

```
# variables
directory="/etc"
backupDirectory="/backup"
incrementalBackup="/incremental"
options=(-a -e 'ssh -p 10022' -b --backup-dir="$incrementalBackup" --delete)
# rsync
rsync "${options[@]}" user@server:"$directory" "$backupDirectory"
```

`eval` is not a safe option to use; it isn't limited to just evaluating the quotations you intend it to, but will evaluate *any* code. It might work for your current situation, but changes to the value of `options` might bring unforeseen consequences, and it's generally a bad idea to get into the habit of using `eval` when it isn't necessary.

Comment: I actually wanted to say: `One option is to use eval`.  +1 for the alternate.

Comment: What is the reason we need to use array or eval with rsync? I mean for other commands, I typically use variable which shell would have replaced before calling the program anyways?