# Bash: Problem with rsync --exclude using variables with spaces?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, escaping, rsync

I have a list of files/folders I wish to exclude from an `rsync` command, in the variable `$rsyncExclude`. Some files/folders have spaces and other special characters ($RECYCLE.BIN) for example.

I'm using the suggestion from @chepner in this question about [how to use `rsync` with options as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219774/bash-rsync-with-options-as-variable), but I'm still having trouble getting `--exclude` to work properly with my use case. Folders such as "/System Volume Information/" etc still copy over.

I've tried using different quotes for `$rsyncExclude`, e.g.

`rsyncExclude="'.cache',` ... `'[$]RECYCLE.BIN/','/System Volume Information/'` ... `"`

and

`rsyncExclude=".cache",` ... `"[$]RECYCLE.BIN/","/System Volume Information/"` ...

and no quotes between:

`rsyncExclude=".cache,` ... `[$]RECYCLE.BIN/,/System Volume Information/` ... `"`

But no luck... What am I doing wrong?

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsyncExclude=".cache/,/dev/,/proc/,/sys/,/tmp/,/mnt/,/media/,/lost+found,/Adobe/,[$]RECYCLE.BIN/,/System Volume Information/,pagefile.sys,/temp/"

From="/home/user/bash/backup/testA/"
To="/home/user/bash/backup/testA backup/"


# variables
# thanks to idea by @chepner (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219774)
options=(--dry-run --verbose --archive --human-readable --progress --stats --delete-after --itemize-changes --exclude={"${rsyncExclude}"} --delete-excluded)
# rsync
rsync "${options[@]}" "${From}" "${To}"
```

**Update:**

Using an array, doesn't seem to work either:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsyncExclude=(".cache/", "/dev/", "/proc/", "/sys/", "/tmp/", "/mnt/", "/media/", "/lost+found", "/Adobe/", "[$]RECYCLE.BIN/", "/System Volume Information/", "pagefile.sys", "/temp/")

From="/home/user/bash/backup/testA/"
To="/home/user/bash/backup/testA backup/"


# variables
# thanks to idea by @chepner (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219774)
options=(--dry-run --verbose --archive --human-readable --progress --stats --delete-after --itemize-changes --exclude={"${rsyncExclude[@]}"} --delete-excluded)
# rsync
rsync "${options[@]}" "${From}" "${To}"
```

I get the following output:

```
rsync: link_stat "/dev/," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/proc/," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/sys/," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/tmp/," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/mnt/," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/media/," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/lost+found," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/Adobe" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/user/bash/backup//[$]RECYCLE.BIN" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/System Volume Information" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/bash/backup/pagefile.sys," failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/temp" failed: No such file or directory (2)
skipping directory .
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Trouble is, those files/paths DO exist in the test directory---i.e. $RECYCLE.BIN, System Volume Information, .cache, pagefile.sys, etc...

Comment: Use an array rather than a plain variable to store the options (see chepner's answer to the linked question). Do *not* use `eval` -- it is full of traps for the unwary. Do not try to store quotes or escapes in variables -- variables are for storing data, not shell syntax (which is what quotes and escapes are).

Comment: Updated question with having an attempt at using an array, but having problems with that also unfortunately! I don't understand this very well. Is this a problem with escaping or something?

Comment: Using variables (including arrays) inside a brace expression (like `--exclude={"${rsyncExclude[@]}"}`) doesn't work, because the shell expands brace expressions before variables. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710476/bash-need-help-passing-a-a-variable-to-rsync/50710691#50710691) for a way to convert an array of paths to a series of `--exclude=` options.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Gordon Davisson, that's got it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for this script, thanks to [@Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710476/bash-need-help-passing-a-a-variable-to-rsync/50710691#50710691)

```
#!/bin/bash

rsyncExclude=(".cache/" "/dev/" "/proc/" "/sys/" "/tmp/" "/mnt/" "/media/" "/lost+found" "/Adobe/" "[$]RECYCLE.BIN/" "/System Volume Information/" "pagefile.sys" "/temp/")

From="./testA a/"
To="./testA-backup wa/"


# using variables
# thanks to idea by @chepner (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219774)
# and solution to expanding the --exclude array, thanks to @ Gordon Davisson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710476
options=(-vahP --dry-run --stats "${rsyncExclude[@]/#/--exclude=}")
# rsync
rsync "${options[@]}" "${From}" "${To}"
```

> `"${rsyncExclude[@]/#/--exclude=}"` does three things; first, the
> `[@]` makes it expand to all of the elements of the array; then the
> `/#/--exclude=` "replaces" the beginning of each element with
> "--exclude=" (essentially, it prepends "--exclude=" to each element)