# rsync with options as variable

Tags: bash, rsync

I read [old topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219774/bash-rsync-with-options-as-variable)

And try do the same *rsync with options as variable* But I get *Warning: Identity file $myVar/ssh_key/my_ssh_key not accessible: No such file or directory.* My code

```
options=(-rvz -e 'ssh -p 22 -i "$myVar"/ssh_key/my_ssh_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no')
rsync "${options[@]}" /home/user/proj/ pi@${IP}:/home/pi/proj/
```

Where $myVar is /home/user/proj/

${IP} is IP address 192.168.1.222

*Warning: Identity file $myVar/ssh_key/my_ssh_key not accessible: No such file or directory.*

This line without $myVar works good

```
rsync -rvz -e 'ssh -p 22 -i /home/user/proj/ssh_key/my_ssh_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --progress /home/user/proj/ pi@${IP}:/home/pi/proj/
```

How I can do rsync with options as variable?

Comment: Variables are not expanded within single quotes.  You have an opening single quote just in front of _ssh_, which gets closed just after _=no_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place `$myVar` inside single quotes, it will not be expanded, resulting in the wrong argument being passed to `ssh`.

To expand it while accounting for possible special characters (spaces and quotes):

```bash
options=(-rvz -e "ssh -p 22 -i ${myVar@Q}/ssh_key/my_ssh_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no")
rsync "${options[@]}" /home/user/proj/ pi@${IP}:/home/pi/proj/
```

Why it works: `${options[2]}` is built by concatenating 3 sections:

1. `ssh -p 22 -i`  (the command line before the variable)
2. `${myVar@Q}` (the expanded variable in a quoted format, documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))
3. `/ssh_key/my_ssh_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` (the rest of the arguments)

For older bash versions without `@Q` support:

```bash
options=(-rvz -e "ssh -p 22 -i $(printf %q "${myVar}")/ssh_key/my_ssh_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no")
```